# system.d custom service not running correctly script.sh but as user can run script.sh manually

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, systemd, services

***[SOLVED]***

My questions is simple,

I created a mcboot.service wich auto start my **All The Mod 8 MC server**, I sysctl enabled it, and did daemon-reload, my issue now is, I can execute without issue the run.sh manually with my user named "agent" but at auto startup I got this on the sysctl status:

```
agent@ubntsrv1: /var/ATM8$ systemctl daemon-reload
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.reload-daemon === Authentication is required to reload the systemd state.
Authenticating as: user (agent)
Password:
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
agent@ubntsrv1: /var/ATM8$ systemctl status mcboot.service
mcboot.service Minecraft boot script
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mcboot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2023-02-02 11:14:20 UTC; 52min ago
Main PID: 718 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
CPU: 350ms
Feb 02 11:14:18 ubntsrv1 systemd[1]: Started Minecraft boot script.
Feb 02 11:14:18 ubntsrv1 run.sh [718]: /var/ATM8
Feb 02 11:14:19 ubntsrv1 run.sh [723]: Error: Could not find or load main class .var.ATM8.user_jvm_args.txt Feb 02 11:14:19 ubntsrv1 run.sh [723]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /var/ATM8/user_jvm_args/txt Feb 02 11:14:20 ubntsrv1 run.sh [718]: /var/ATM8
Feb 02 11:14:20 ubntsrv1 systemd[1]: mcboot.service: Deactivated successfully.
agent@ubntsry1:/var/ATM8$
```

Here is content of my run.sh :

```
#!/bin/env sh
# Forge requires a configured set of both JVM and program arguments.
# Add custom JVM arguments to the user_jvm_args.txt
# Add custom program arguments (such as noguil to this file in the next line before the "$@" or
# pass them to this script directly
BASEDIR=$(dirname "$0")
echo "$BASEDIR"
java @user_jvm_args.txt @libraries/net/minecraftforge/forge/1.19.2-43.2.3/unix_args.txt BASEDIR=$(dirname "$0")
echo "$BASEDIR"
```

and here is my mcboot.service :

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft boot script
[Service]
ExecStart=/var/ATM8/run.sh start
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I want to do it right I don't want to use crontab.

Thx

**[EDIT SOLVED]**

*Does your script work when you run it manually from a different directory, e.g. cd /tmp; /var/ATM8/run.sh start? (I guess not.) Try cd "$BASEDIR" before java ...*

*This actually fixed my issue ! I could run my script manually from everywhere, but actually adding the ***cd $BASEDIR*** made the service work succesfully and it's now running everytime my R820 restarts !* thx

Comment: Does your script work when you run it manually from a different directory, e.g. `cd /tmp; /var/ATM8/run.sh start`? (I guess not.) Try `cd "$BASEDIR"` before `java ...`. Please [edit] your question to add information.

Comment: 1. You may need to add a user and group to your unit file. Edit mcboot.service and add the following lines under the `[Service]` block.
`User=YourUser` followed by `Group=YourGroup`.
 2. You may need to have the proper Environment Variables exported.
 3. Not sure why you have `start` in `ExecStart=/var/ATM8/run.sh start`. Your are not looking for any arguments in your `run.sh` script.